# Opentext -Webservice to add Records to Database

Tags: api, opentext

Dears,

I have OpenText ECM with Several Documents, I need to add one more Column to an existing table of OpenText DB.I have another DB in DB2 with all the information, I need a solution for updating Column from DB2 Table to SQL Table of OpenText both tables has a unique value.

Comment: Hi, I don't think modifying the core table would be a good idea.It would affect the solution in many ways.Could you tell me what is the problem you have to solve?

Comment: I have Physical Items created and need to add more column via web service or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Don't change OpenText core tables. Never. I'm sure you can achive your goal by create a new table and a foreign key that reference the table you would like to modify.